# Collect RadioButton selection when creating last fragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to get the selected values of first second and third screen to be used in the final fourth screen. How would I go about accessing the radio groups of the previous fragments?

I have tried to store the selected value in the onPause method of each fragment but it gets called when I slide from the first fragment to the third fragment and not from the first to the second.

I have tried to use a listener for the radiogroup but it never gets called.

I have tried to access the other three fragments from the final Tsiatista fragment but without any success.

```
package com.tsiatistonmyfriend;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Locale;
import net.justanotherblog.swipeview.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;
public static String funnySerious;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
// primary sections of the app.
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

// Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);       
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() 
{   
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;

funnySerious = (String) rb.getText();                   
}                
};  

/**
* A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
* one of the sections/tabs/pages.
*/
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) 
{
super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) 
{           
Fragment fragment = new FunnySerious();

switch (position) 
{
case 0:
return fragment = new FunnySerious();
case 1:
return fragment = new MaleFemale();
case 2:
return fragment = new DirtyClean();
case 3:
return fragment = new Tsiatisto();
default:
break;
}       

return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
// Show 4 total pages.
return 4;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
switch (position) {
case 0:
return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
case 1:
return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
case 2:
return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
case 3:
return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
}
return null;
}
}


public static class FunnySerious extends Fragment 
{       
View v;

public FunnySerious() {}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.funny_serious, container, false);

v = rootView;

return rootView;
}           
}

public static class MaleFemale extends Fragment
{       
public MaleFemale() {}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.male_female, container, false);

return rootView;
}       
}

public static class DirtyClean extends Fragment
{       
public DirtyClean() {}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dirty_clean, container, false);

return rootView;
}       
}

public static class Tsiatisto extends Fragment
{       
public Tsiatisto() {}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
//FunnySerious textFragment = (FunnySerious) this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pager);


View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tsiatisto, container, false);

DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());         

try 
{
myDbHelper.createDataBase(); 
myDbHelper.openDataBase();
}catch(IOException ioe) 
{ 
throw new Error("Unable to create database"); 
}        

final SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getDB();       

Cursor cursor;
cursor =  db.query("Tsiatista ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", new String[] { "*" }, null, null, null, null, null);
//cursor =  db.rawQuery("SELECT Verse FROM Tsiatista WHERE ID = 1", null);

if(cursor.moveToFirst())
{                   
String htr;
htr = (String) cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Verse"));

EditText et = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tsiatistoTxt);
et.setText(htr);

cursor.close();
}

return rootView;
}       
}
}
```

Comment: I have made it possible to access the radiobuttons by adding the views in an arraylist and then accessing them succesfully. Here is the code used:

 View fs;
 RadioGroup rg;
 int selectedId;
 RadioButton rb;

 fs = (View) mViews.get(0);
 rg = (RadioGroup) fs.findViewById(R.id.radioGroupFS);
 selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
 rb = (RadioButton) fs.findViewById(selectedId);
 funnySerious = (String) rb.getText();  

However the problem is that I don't know where to place this in order to get executed when the last fragment is made visible. Anywhere I place it, it get executed premature.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways,

1. Pass selected values as key value boolean pair in form of bundle, using setArgument method when you switch between fragment. You can then access this passed bundle and use selected values from previous fragment to drive you logic further, you can then club this values with values from current fragment and and navigate it further.
2. Read about shared preferences, you can always save value persistently and access it from all over your application, so using this you can save value selected by user from first three fragment, retrieve it on fourth and complete your logic.

Hope it help.

Comment: how do I know I switch between fragments. I mean which part of the code is this?

Comment: OnCreate of a fragment will  be called whenever its loaded, in your code you are using ViewPager with a adapter, its better you load all the checked item from user in sort of global variable or preferences. else in your geItem method you are returning fragment just setArgument with bundle there and access it on another.

Comment: I have made it possible to access the radiobuttons by adding the views in an arraylist and then accessing them succesfully. Here is the code used: View fs; RadioGroup rg; int selectedId; RadioButton rb; fs = (View) mViews.get(0); rg = (RadioGroup) fs.findViewById(R.id.radioGroupFS); selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId(); rb = (RadioButton) fs.findViewById(selectedId); funnySerious = (String) rb.getText(); However the problem is that I don't know where to place this in order to get executed when the last fragment is made visible. Anywhere I place it, it get executed premature